# bar progress stop working with "display: inline-block;" property

Tags: html, css, angularjs, progress-bar

I'm writing something for the new job and I'm having a problem with the progress bar.
I created the bar along with the number represented, ie if the number is 50 then half of the bar will be filled (as usual).

But when I put the bar and the number on the same line (with display: inline-block), the filling of the bar disappears. Without this property, the bar looks right but the number is not aligned to the same height

html:

```
            <div style="width:100%;">
                 <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar" style="width:{{value}}%"></div>
                 </div>
                <span class="value">{{value | number:0}}</span>
            </div>
```

css:

```
.progress {
    height: 0.3rem;
    width: 90%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.value {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

i dont understand the issue.. need your help.

TNX!!!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the wonders of FlexBox?

If you are unfamiliar with this, here is a link: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Basically you can do the following:
https://jsfiddle.net/nL3pr8vw/2/

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.load {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;
  background: grey;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.bar {
  width: 45%;
  background: red;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height:25px;
}

p {
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="load">
  <div class="bar">
    <span class="count"><p>45%</p></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Now with this code, you can just re-arrange the divs and mess around with the FlexBox in the CSS to get your desired result!*